# How to make div occupy remaining height?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have this problem, I have two divs:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:50px;" id="div1"></div>
<div style="width:100%;" id="div2"></div>
```

How do I make div2 occupy remaining height of the page?

Comment: Should there ever be a vertical scrollbar? What happens when the content inside `#div2` is taller than the window?

Comment: use a table set to height=100%. use 2 rows instead of 2 divs

Comment: Don't use tables when there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use absolute positioning:

```css
#div1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:red;/*Development Only*/
}
#div2{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color:blue;/*Development Only*/
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 23):

You can use this http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/S8g4E/783/

```
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
#container > div{
    display: table-row;
    height: 0;
}
#container > div.fill{
    height: auto;
}
```

Just apply the class `.fill` to any of the children to make then occupy the remaining height.

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="fill">   <!-- this will fill the remaining height-->
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>
</div>
```

It works with how many children you want, no additional markup is required.

Comment: this is great but if you change #container.height: 400px to #container.height = 100% is does not work any more. Is there a way to make to container fill the available height?

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. It's a bit ridiculous that the only way to accomplish this with variable heights is by using tables or JavaScript. They get a bad rap, but tables did a lot of things right.

Comment: @Gavin a `div` with `display: table` is not a table.

Comment: @herman it behaves the same as a table. It's the behavior of tables that got a bad rap, not that it was named "table".

Comment: @Gavin as far as I know it's the fact that a semantic element like `<table>` should not be used for layout purposes.  `display: table` provides a way to get similar behaviour without implying the same semantics.

Comment: Does not seem to have any effect in firefox v123

Answer (score 13):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pWfjJ/)

One way is to set the the div to `position:absolute` and give it a top of 50px and bottom of 0px;

```
#div2
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    top:50px
}
```

Comment: What if there are other elements with heights which aren't fixed?

Comment: @Mark: good point. This solution doesn't work if the preceding elements have a dynamic or unknown height. In this case I think the only solution would be javascript. Like here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023512/how-can-i-make-a-div-take-up-the-rest-of-the-height-of-a-container-div

Answer (score 9):

Since you know how many pixels are occupied by the previous content, you can use the `calc()` function:

```
height: calc(100% - 50px);
```

Comment: @kalu Only Opera Mini, IE8 and old stock Android browser (4.3) won't work.  Nobody cares about IE8 and Android 4.3 market share is negligible.  Opera Mini has more market share, but seems to lack support for a lot of modern things.  You could specify a fallback height as a percentage on the line before, which will get overridden in browsers that support calc.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same challenge myself and found these 2 answers using `flex` properties.

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dynamic-element{
  flex: 1;
}
```

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35348188/1084619
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35348188/1084619

Comment: This is really the only solution that doesn't require the TOP position to be fixed, which means the upper portion can vary in height.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
display: flex;
```

CSS property, as mentioned before by @Ayan, but I've created a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/d2kjxd51/

Comment: Beware of browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex (especially if you want the solution to work on IE)

Answer (score 5):

With CSS tables, you could wrap a div around the two you have there and use this css/html structure:

```
<style type="text/css">
.container { display:table; width:100%; height:100%;  }
#div1 { display:table-row; height:50px; background-color:red; }
#div2 { display:table-row; background-color:blue; }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Depends on what browsers support these display types, however. I don't think IE8 and below do. EDIT: Scratch that-- IE8 does support CSS tables.

Comment: height 100% is not making the height 100%

Comment: Your html,body also need to be height:100%

Answer (score 1):

I tried with CSS, and or you need to use display: table or you need to use new css that is not yet supported on most browsers (2016).

So, I wrote a jquery plugin to do it for us, I am happy to share it:

```js
 
//Credit Efy Teicher
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".fillHight").fillHeight();
            $(".fillWidth").fillWidth();
        });

        window.onresize = function (event) {
            $(".fillHight").fillHeight();
            $(".fillWidth").fillWidth();
        }

        $.fn.fillHeight = function () {
            var siblingsHeight = 0;
            this.siblings("div").each(function () {
                siblingsHeight = siblingsHeight + $(this).height();
            });

            var height = this.parent().height() - siblingsHeight;
            this.height(height);
        };

 
        $.fn.fillWidth = function (){
            var siblingsWidth = 0;
            this.siblings("div").each(function () {
                siblingsWidth  += $(this).width();
            });

            var width =this.parent().width() - siblingsWidth;
            this.width(width);
        }
```

```css
      * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        html {
        }

        html, body, .fillParent {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fillParent" style="background-color:antiquewhite">
        <div>
            no1
        </div>
        <div class="fillHight">
            no2 fill
        </div>
        <div class="deb">
            no3
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `calc` function to calculate remaining height for 2nd div.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#div1{
  height: 50px;
  background: skyblue;
}

#div2{
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="content">content</div>
  <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>

#header {
  height: 200px;
}

#content {
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -200px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

#footer {
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: please, add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: @AlexKM sorry for my poor English.#content will occupy remaining height of the outer div.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use padding with negative margins?  Something like this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
  </div>
</div>
```

And then

```
.parent {
  padding-top: 1em;
}
.child1 {
  margin-top: -1em;
  height: 1em;
}
.child2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```