# CSS Div fill remaining height

Tags: html, css, alignment

Please see my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ugjfwbg4/)

I want the green middle `div` to fill the remaining space of the wrapper `div` no matter how much content it has.

If it matters I'm including bootstrap too.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Give the container:

```
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
```

and for the element:

```
flex:1;
```

---

The demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/ugjfwbg4/1/

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.mid {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.left{
  flex:1;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="top"></div>

  <div class="mid">
    
    <div class="left">left</div>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks John. on this fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ugjfwbg4/2/) the red div inside of the green does not stretch to 100% can you explain?

Comment: Give according css rules to container and child as before. https://jsfiddle.net/ugjfwbg4/3/ and check out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/