# How to size an inner div to make an area take up 100% of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page like this:

```
<body>
<div class="outerdiv">
<div class="someDiv">
<div class="flexible"></div>
</div>
<div class="someOtherDiv"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

I need to write css and javascript to make this layout take up 100% of the screen by adjusting the size of the flexible div.

I especially appreciate solutions that can handle complex scenarios with flexible div being nested in other divs and the content being a not known in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a "here is what I want, give me a solution" kind of site. You should try to solve this on your own and post your code when you get stuck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a DIV take up the rest of the height of a container div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023512/how-can-i-make-a-div-take-up-the-rest-of-the-height-of-a-container-div)

Comment: Try `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` for the flexible div.

Answer (score 1):

By default divs are 100% of the width of its container.  So if the container holding flexible is not 100% width of the document then it will not be.  You can position absolute and give it a specific width but it will have to be changed as the window grows or shrinks.

```
<script>
$(window).resize(function(){
  var windowWidth =  $(window).width();
  $(".flexible").width(windowWidth);
});
</script>
```