# How to stretch the table to fill all available space

Tags: html, css

This question might be simple, but I cannot find an answer.

I have the following html:

```
<div>
  some text
  <div>
    <table>
        <tr><td>
            Test
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
body,html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

table {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
}
```

How can I stretch the table vertically **without** change of the height property of `div`? I want the `table` to have `height: 100%` but it does not work because the outer containers do not have a fixed height (as I understand).

http://jsfiddle.net/8qedxug9/

Comment: Try this `div{
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}`

Comment: Yes, but I have deep structure in real case, I cannot affect so many divs... Also if content is bigger than viewport I need scrolling. `Overflow: hidden` will break this (

Comment: Add id to your div and then add your css to it. That way only specific div will be affected.

Comment: @HassanImam something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kobknbn7/
It does not work. It looks I need update height of all divs :(

Comment: Along with that add following css `div{
  height:inherit;
}`

Comment: It will affect all divs, It will force to inherit the value of body. So the same as just to set 100% height to all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159134/discussion-between-hassan-imam-and-serg046).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `height: 100%` to `div` element. In case you don't want scrolling, add `overflow:hidden;`.

```css
body,html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

div{
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

table {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  some text
  <div>
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Test
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've chosen this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818467/how-to-apply-100-height-to-div

Answer (score 0):

To change height property to always have 100% of window height you should use `view height` CSS unit like this:

```css
body,html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

table {
    height: 95vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  some text
  <div>
    <table>
        <tr><td>
            Test
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean vertical space

Comment: You want to increase vertical space of table ?

Comment: Yes, I want table to have `height: 100%`
But outer containers do not have fixed height and it does not work :(

Comment: Hmm, it looks as a right way. But scrolling is appeared.

Comment: Just use 95vh instead of 100 or use overflow: hidden

Comment: Good approach but it does not work in different resolution. Some content in div can take different vh height. So e.g. I have 5vh content in fullhd, but in hd it will take more space, maybe 8vh. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

If an HTML element's default width and height is relative to its parent. So in this instance, the table is 100% of the height of its parent Div element. The Div that the table is in will therefore, also need to have a height of 100%.

In your Fiddle, adding a 100% height to all div's makes the div stretch to 100% of the body height, and thus the table stretch to 100% height also:

```
body,html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    height: 100%;
}

table {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
}

td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to declare the `height` of an element relatively (in `%`), you will need to declare the `height` of its parent element. So, you'll **need** to declare the `height`s of your `divs`:

```
<div>
  some text
  <div>
    <table>
        <tr><td>
            Test
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body,html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
}

table {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
}
```